# State variable equations for a RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, state-space, equation

What are the state variable equations of this RLC circuit? How do I write the final matrix? I tried to write the equations for the capacitor and inductor:

$$L\frac{di_3}{dt}=v_1-v_C \leftrightarrow \frac{di_3}{dt}=\frac{v_1}{L}-\frac{v_C}{L}$$

$$C\frac{dv_C}{dt}=i_3\leftrightarrow \frac{dv_C}{dt}=\frac{1}{C}i_3$$

I tried to apply the Kirchoff's law:

(1) $$i_1R_1+L\frac{di_3}{dt}+v_C=v(t)\leftrightarrow i_1=\frac{v(t)}{R_1}-\frac{L}{R_1}\frac{di_3}{dt}-\frac{v_C}{R_1}$$

(2)

$$v_1=v(t)-R_1i_1$$

From these equations I am unable to reach the final matrix. How could I go on?

[image]

Comment: The purpose is to find the voltage across the capacitor? And it is an AC-circuit? You can use complex analysis.

Comment: She did not specify steady state voltage applied. The voltage source may have a transient component

Comment: Carmen, [this should](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/signalssystems/Lecture11_12.pdf) help you.

Answer (score 1):

The inductor equation:
$$L i_3'=v_1-v_C$$

The capacitor equation:
$$c v_c'=i_3\ \ \ (1)$$

Kirchoff's current law:
$$\frac{u-v_1}{R_1}=i_3+\frac{v_1}{R_2}$$

which can be solved for \$v_1\$ to get
$$v_1=\frac{R_2 \left(u-i_3 R_1\right)}{R_1+R_2}$$

Substitute this in the inductor equation 
$$L i_3'=\frac{R_2 \left(u-i_3 R_1\right)}{R_1+R_2}-v_c \ (2)$$

The equations (2) and (1) can then be put in matrix form as

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 i_3' \\
 v_c' \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{R_1 R_2}{L \left(R_1+R_2\right)} & -\frac{1}{L} \\
 \frac{1}{c} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 i_3 \\
 v_c \\
\end{array}
\right)+
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{R_2}{L \left(R_1+R_2\right)} \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) u$$

Verifying using Mathematica.
[image]